# My PostgreSQL Docker image stops to run afer add a CMD

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I have an image based on `mdillon/postgis` to serve a PostgreSQL server.

Just added some code into my Dockerfile to add java OpenJDK from official OpenJDK Dockerfile for same distro ( merge `FROM mdillon/postgis` with the code from the OpenJDK ). The result is too long and S.O. complains about that so I can't post here.

After that all is working very fine and I have a Postgres server with java. I can prove this by running `java -version` in console and accessing the server using my PGAdmin4.

My trouble starts when I put some application there ( Spring Boot ) and try to run it using

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/opt/lib/odisseu-1.0.war"]
```

My application runs fine ( I can access it ) but the Postgres server stops to run. Inspecting the `Container statistics` in my Portainer I can see the postgres processes are not running.

This is the container running without my java app:
[image]

And this is the container running after start the application using `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`:

[image]

My question: What can I do to run java applications in a PostgreSQL derivated image?

**EDIT** Please avoid to do what I'm doing ( put more than one service in a container ) because you'll brake some microsservices good practices. I need to do this because I must use a very tiny service to control some filesystem aspects from other services. Is a very particular case.

Comment: Yes, `Do not put a microsservice and a database in same container` you'll say. I realy need this configuration for a very particular case.

Comment: It is correct that Stack Overflow complains about questions that are over 30K long. That is probably a good thing - if a log file or code is that long, it needs to be cut down to a [mcve].

Comment: Can you outline, by way of a question edit, why you want to put multiple services into one container? Someone may have a better way of approaching the problem.

Comment: @halfer It's ok. But the Dockerfile code is large and will not make sense if I (not the code writer) cut it somehow. About your second question: I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mdillon/postgis` image is based on `postgres:alpine` image.
This image use an `entrypoint` and a `cmd` to start postrgresql when container start. see [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.5/alpine/Dockerfile#L151). So in your case you erase cmd and postrgresql entrypoint.

If you want to start java and postgresql you can add both command in your own bash script in command or entrypoint.

btw, I advice you to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to start postgresql and java in two different containers better, safer and easier.

Comment: About start postgresql and java in two different containers I already said why I don't want to do this. I'll inspect the original base container to see how to start both services. Thanks.